# How to implement this Android layout?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

[image]

At the top there is the favorites/styles/all channels
i don't know what that widget/control is i need to know what it is
i am certain i saw it before i just can't seem to find it again.

then there is a listview which is easy to implement **no help needed there**

then the same control again, i need to know how to build it.
it looks like a native Android control, i know how i can make one just like it using image buttons but i am sure i am missing something.

P.S. this is an image from sky.fm app on android

**EDIT:** I Do no need help with the ListView i already did that
What i do need help with is how to make the "favorites/styles/all channels" buttons if there is a way to do natively.
If there isn't a way to do natively, and you are sure just say there isn't a way to do natively ( that would be a good answer )
the perfect answer would be a working code, but i am not lazy i am already implementing the code my self

Comment: if all widget associated different elements, use Tab else use Button/ToggleButton . no natiove controll at all .

Comment: On your edit: Just make images and apply them to the buttons. Is that really all you need help with?

Comment: i needed to make sure there was no native control for it while i was making custom stuff that wouldn't be as good

Comment: Maria Neumayer gave me the necessary hint for me to succeed in doing these buttons.

Comment: If someone comments here telling me the name of the native iOS control that is just like these buttons i will later make a tutorial and post it here to make it's equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native control for this. It's probably a Button or maybe ToggleButton. You could create a background xml with different states for selected true or false. And when you click the button toggle the selected state.

Comment: Thanks for "You could create a background xml with different states for selected true or false"

Comment: I am actually very close to doing it now with your hint, the drawable xml is very flexible it allowed me to do it without having to create bg images just with gradients, thankssssssssssssssssssss.

Answer (score 0):

Top might be a custom tab layout, or just a bunch of buttons with custom styling.

Main part looks like a listview with complex row views.

Bottom almost definately is a bunch of buttons.

Comment: i'd +1 your post because you read my question, but clearly i have said the same thing in my post, i quote myself "i know how i can make one just like it using image buttons" and having their background altered programatically

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using ClickableListAdapter.There is also tab implementation.try it.

Comment: i quote my self "then there is a listview which is easy to implement no help needed there"

Answer (score 0):

Just make it using image buttons and put filters in your ListView, or create your own filter form scratch !

Comment: i have no problems with the list view i already have it working fine with the same style, why does everyone keep commenting on the list view.